# Execute python code indefinetly when key is pressed

Tags: python

I'm a bit new to python so I don't know exactly how to do this. I was trying to create a script that would help me automate doing tasks in a game. When I created this script, I got stuck on how to execute code whenever the key was pressed (I.e. when f is pressed, the line of code will execute). However, I keep running into the problem where the script would execute anyway without my input and would then die. I want my script to be running indefinitely until closed and respond to keyboard inputs. Thanks

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import pyautogui
import keyboard  # Dormant module

pykeyboard = Controller()


def right():  # This is the action I want to do
    time.sleep(1)
    pykeyboard.press('d')
    pyautogui.keyDown("space")
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.keyUp("space")
    pykeyboard.release('d')


def left():
    time.sleep(1)
    pykeyboard.press('a')
    pyautogui.keyDown("space")
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.keyUp("space")
    pykeyboard.release('a')


time.sleep(3)

if input == 'r':  # This listens to input
    left()  # This creates output

if input == 't':
    right()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a structure found in every game and operating system: a control loop. Normally, programming guides will tell you not to do this, but in this specific case, it's an absolute necessity:

```
while True:
    
    if input == 't':
        right()
    elif input == 'r':
        left()
    elif input == 'q':
        break

    time.sleep(3)
```

This code will take input every iteration and execute the desired function, unless that input is equal to your quit signal ('q' in this example). You'll also want to include a sleep parameter to avoid spamming your events.

Comment: Hi, I tried this out and tinkering it around but the function just doesn't want to execute whenever I press 't' or 'r'. However this fixed the script from dying out. Could the issue be on my end as the keystrokes aren't being registered by the python script? I tried typing the keys within the game, a browser, and a text file, but nothing is working. Do you know a workaround? Thanks

Comment: @Emerald47 I have to admit to being somewhat confused by your code. Normally, the `input` keyword is used to indicate accepting input from the terminal but you're using it in an unusual way. How do you expect to get `'t'`, `'r'` and `'q'`?

Comment: I expect to press down the keys 't' 'r' and 'q' on my keyboard in order to execute the functions defined as 'right' and 'left'. These functions will be performed on a game. Also I'm a bit new to python and am trying to learn it. Sorry if the code may be confusing. Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I failed to let you know that my inputs were going to be keystrokes thats why my script wasn't working. I made the program running by changing your code to `while True:

    if keyboard.read_key() == "t":
        right()
    if keyboard.read_key() == "r":
        left()
    if keyboard.read_key() == "q":
        break

time.sleep(1) `. Thanks for helping me figure this out!

Comment: @Emerald47 Okay, that makes sense. Glad I could be of help